# Web installer for a local site

Tags: php, web

I have made a website(in php). THe website is installed on a local server. But the problem is I have to insall the same site to multiple locations. 
My concern is that I do not want to move everytime I have to install the site to those locations. Is it possible to just have the site in a repository online, and have people downloading the setup and install it(Including the environment requirements,i.e. Wamp,...).
THanks in advance

Comment: Yes you can put your source code in repository so other people can update site from it. Or you can set up some automation deployment tool, for example in http://www.capistranorb.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like these:

1. [**BitNami**](http://bitnami.com/) - Run your favorite apps locally or in the cloud in minutes.
2. [**Server2Go**](http://www.server2go-web.de/) - Webserver that runs out of the box without any installation and on write protected media.
3. [**ExeOutput**](http://www.exeoutput.com/) for PHP lets you create applications in native format for Windows with PHP, JavaScript and HTML.
4. [**Stack**](http://stackphp.com/) - By wrapping your application in decorators you can add new behaviour from the outside.